# how to set a inner div in center and expands equally top and bottom based on content size

Tags: html, css

I have a inner div with a text div., I`m trying to keep the inner text div positioned in middle and increase size of text div equally both from top and bootm based on content size. Here is my approach I tried so far, may I know what more changes I can do to achieve it.

```css
.outerdiv{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid;
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 position:relative;
 top:20%;
 left:35%;
}
.innerdiv{
 position:absolute;
 /*top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:-45px;*/
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:#ccc;
 margin:auto;
}
.textcontainer{
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px;
}
.textcomponent{
 border:1px solid;
 background: #b9a06f;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
   <div class="innerdiv">
      <div class="textcontainer">
         <div class="textcomponent">
            <h2>This is title section</h2>
            <br/>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, all you need is to make the inner a flexbox container like you did with the outer one

```css
.outerdiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 35%;
}

.innerdiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: auto;
}

.textcontainer {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textcomponent {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #b9a06f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <div class="textcontainer">
      <div class="textcomponent">
        <h2>This is title section</h2>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the height to be adjusted based on The content. So I removed Flex from the outerdiv along with the constrained height of 300px, I also removed the height constraint form the innnerdiv and set its posistion to relative.

```css
.outerdiv{
 width:300px;
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid;
 display: block;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 position:relative;
 top:20%;
 left:35%;
}
.innerdiv{
 position:relative;
 /*top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:-45px;*/
 width:200px;
 background:#ccc;
 margin:auto;
}
.textcontainer{
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px;
}
.textcomponent{
 border:1px solid;
 background: #b9a06f;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
   <div class="innerdiv">
      <div class="textcontainer">
         <div class="textcomponent">
            <h2>This is title section</h2>
            <br/>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or if you intended to keep the height constrained you can hide the overflow in the innderdiv:

```css
.outerdiv{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid;
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 position:relative;
 top:20%;
 left:35%;
}
.innerdiv{
 position:absolute;
 /*top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:-45px;*/
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
 background:#ccc;
 margin:auto;
}
.textcontainer{
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px;
}
.textcomponent{
 border:1px solid;
 background: #b9a06f;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
   <div class="innerdiv">
      <div class="textcontainer">
         <div class="textcomponent">
            <h2>This is title section</h2>
            <br/>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to remove height as it is a parsys (standard position) where the components I drag drop show be able to position as per the requirement.

Comment: Gotcha, I was concerned about the over-flow getting too large when more text was added, and leaving the size fixed wasn't mentioned in the question. No worries. I'll leave the answer up it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```css
.outerdiv {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.innerdiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: inherit;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.textcontainer {
    padding: 10px;
}
.textcomponent{
 border:1px solid;
 background: #b9a06f;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
   <div class="innerdiv">
      <div class="textcontainer">
         <div class="textcomponent">
            <h2>This is title section</h2>
            <br/>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```